# Uniformly convergent sequence of polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, uniform-convergence

Prove or disprove. The limit of a uniformly convergent sequence of polynomial is differentiable.

Comment: On a bounded or unbounded interval ?

Comment: @EwanDelanoy: That's a naughty question. 8)

Comment: @Michael: Have you heard about the [Stone–Weierstrass theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem)?

Comment: @EwanDelanoy, the domain is not specified...so I am thinking the question assumed arbitrary domain.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen...yea...but weierstrass works on bounded interval. This question is an arbitrary interval.

Comment: It seems that if the interval is infinite, then a difference between two polinomias is bounded iff it is a constant. So, in this case the limit of uniformly convergent sequence of polynomials should be a polynomial. :-)

Comment: May I know where you found this problem?

Answer (score 2):

There are functions which are everywhere continuous and nowhere differentiable. Check the **Weierstrass Function** : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function

Then, in a closed interval, by a well-known theorem of Weierstrass you can approximate such a function uniformly by polynomials. However, the limit is nowhere differentiable.